# Difference between match binding and match destructuring?

Tags: rust, match

Recently I was reading about the `match` keyword in the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/flow_control/match.html). What confused me was the difference between `Binding` and `Destructuring`. In my understanding, both of these provide a way to access variables in an expression. `Binding` can specify a range matching, but you can achieve it with `Destructuring` and [`Guards`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/guard.html). So can someone show some cases that only `Binding` can do or explain the real difference between these two concepts?

Comment: I guess document has a lack of one kind of example, you can bind the whole pattern, this is not possible with destructing and guards, please check:  https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5a68f5834d572dedbbb25df6d29a36b0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see one scenario when a binding is needed because destructuring doesn't satisfy our current need. If we simply destructure the struct we get access to the inner field of the struct. This means that the values used on the right hand side in the match arm won't have access to the methods defined on the struct.

In my example I also match against a specific value of `ex.value`, this is of course not necessary and can be done with a guard instead, this way is however more concise if the condition isn't very complex.

```rust
struct Example {
    some_value: i32,
    some_other_value: String
}

impl Example {
    pub fn some_fn(&mut self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let ex = Example { some_value: 42, some_other_value: "Foobar".to_string() };
    
    match ex {
        mut new_ex @ Example { some_value: 43, .. } => new_ex.some_fn(),
        Example { some_value: first, some_other_value: second } => println!("first value: {}\nSecond value: {}", first, second),
    }
}
```